# Filtering Values in a JSON File and Changing the Value for a Specific Index

Tags: typescript

I have a block of code like this:

```
jsonFile.items.forEach((item) => {
    if ([4, 1].includes(item.index)) {
        item.property = property1;
    } else if ([2, 22, 9].includes(item.index)) {
        item.property = property2;
    }
  });
```

I want to update the values of specific items in the JSON file. Specifically, I want to change the values for indices 4 and 1 to one set of values, and for indices 2, 22, and 9 to another set of values. Is there a more efficient approach to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to answer a question about efficiency without knowing the format of the JSON file.

If you're sure of the format, there are some things you could do:

1. Assumption: indices are unique, ordered and there are no gaps
   Example: `[ { index: 0 }, { index: 1 }, { index: 2 }, ... ]`
   Optimization: Don't loop over all items, but use the array index:

   ```
   jsonFile.items[1].property = property1;
   jsonFile.items[2].property = property2;
   jsonFile.items[4].property = property1;
   ...
   ```

   Considerations: You might want to include some sanity checks

   - Check if the item exists first
   - Check if the item at the array index does indeed have the expected `index`.
2. Assumption: indices are unique, ordered and but there can be gaps
   Example: `[ { index: 0 }, { index: 2 }, ... ]`
   Optimization: Don't loop over all items, but stop once you've reached an index which is equal or higher than the highest (`22`) you're looking for. Meaning at max you'll be looping over 22 items instead of the full length of the items array.
3. Assumption: indices are unique, but unordered and there can be gaps
   Example: `[ { index: 1 }, { index: 0 }, ... ]`
   Optimization: Don't loop over all items, but stop once you've replaced all indices you're looking for. Meaning you can keep track of the indexes you've already found, or the ones you're yet to find.
4. Assumption: the modification is simple, but the JSON is huge
   Optimization: You might not need to parse the JSON or loop over it. Perhaps the replacement could be done through something like a replacement using a regular expression?
5. Assumption: Your're looking for minor optimizations, because the replacement needs to be done constantly and on very large files where any milisecond counts.
   Optimization: Profile different solutions! You might want to consider using a mapping object which indicates which index should be replaced by what value and checking for each item if the index is in the mapping object.
   I doubt this will make much difference at all.
6. ...

But again, the quality of the answer you receive will depend on how many details you provide about the format of the JSON file.